# Correctly link my buttons to my views (in UINavigationController)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, uibutton

I'm sorry if this question sounds kinda newbie, but I'm a beginner and want to improve. So, I have a Navigation Controller embedding my whole application. My main view has a button, linking to another view.

Here is what I did in my main view:

.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

In .m, some code for my button.

In IB, I've added a button in my main view and another ViewController whose I changed the class. And the following links :

- button -> Button
- button -> OtherViewController (Push)

Now my question is, what do I miss to add in my code or IB ? Do I need an IBAction too ?

Thanks a lot for your advices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{

if (!createViewController) {
                createViewController = [[CreateViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateViewController" bundle:nil];

            }

            UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem;
            [backBarButtonItem release];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:createViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a method that defines the action for your button.

In .h:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

In .m:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender { // what you want to do when the button is pressed }
```

Then click on the button from your interface, from Connection Inspector, control click the radio button from "Touch Up Inside", connect to File's Owner and select the method -buttonPressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have 2 questions :

- Do I need to remove the IB link button -> OtherController (Push) ?

- How can I display my other view by the code ?

Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Inside your method buttonPressed, you need: YourViewController *resultView = [[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:resultView animated:NO];
[resultView release];